# Why do indexOf() and findIndex() work differently with Number.isNaN?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I was trying to find `NaN` in array. And I've found this way to do it.

```js
console.log([1, NaN, 3].findIndex(Number.isNaN)); //1
```

And then I've tried to do the same with `indexOf`. Why it's not working?

```js
console.log([1, NaN, 3].indexOf(Number.isNaN)); //-1
```

Comment: You asked this five minutes ago.

Comment: one does not take a function.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the documentation of [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), you will see it does not take a function to compare. It does a strict equality so it is looking for `Number.isNaN` in the array.